# File which responds to isatty(3)

Tags: c, linux, unix, file, tty

I'm wanting to write my own psuedo-shell and would like to get pretty colors etc. How do I go about tricking a subprocess into thinking that it is in a TTY? I've read about virtual TTY's but haven't found much practical information about how to either create one or how that makes a subprocess think that `isatty(stdout) == 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for are called pseudoterminals, pseudo-ttys or ptys. These exist in master/slave pairs, that behave similarly to socket pairs (the bidirectional version of pipes; what is written to one end can be read on the other). In the controlling process, use [`posix_openpt`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_openpt.html) to open a master, then `ptsname` to get the slave's name (probably `/dev/pts/X`):

```
int master = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
grantpt(master);     /* change ownership and permissions */
unlockpt(master);    /* must be called before obtaining slave */
int slave = open(ptsname(master), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
```

As usual, each function can fail, so add error checking. The `slave` fd now refers to the slave device. Use `dup2(slave, STDOUT_FILENO)` in the child process to set standard output to the slave pseudoterminal; similarly for stdin and stderr.

(Note that [some Linux manpages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_openpt) incorrectly state that `posix_openpt` returns `char *`. Also, don't get confused by the `openpty` family of functions; these represent an older interface to pseudo-ttys that is deprecated.)

Comment: In addition to `STDOUT_FILENO`, you should also `dup` the pty slave to the child's `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`.